# How can I start a whole SaS procedure of an open sas egp file via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sas

I have a SaS egp file where I want to run the whole procedure of it via some macro in VBA.
So far I could manage to open the SaS egp file with

Dim o as Variant
o = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open(strPath)

where strPath is the path of the egp file.

Now its open but it does not run atomatically even though I set up auotexecute in the settings.

My goal overall is to run the sas egp file check when it is done and then extract an excel file from a table at the end.

I would appreciate any help to this. Thank you!

Comment: Lots of information out there if you search for it.  Try starting with https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/examples/SASGF2012/Hemedinger_298-2012.pdf